# Launch Spring web application using Spring Boot

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I am trying to launch an **existing** web application using **Spring Boot**, without changing my existing application at all and keeping the spring-boot specific stuff in a **separate module**. I have the following maven structure:

```
parent
  web-app
  boot-app
```

I want to launch the `web-app` from the `boot-app`.

**My boot module**

pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Web Application -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>my.group.id.</groupId>
            <artifactId>web-app</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <classifier>classes</classifier>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Application.java:

```java
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ImportResource("classpath:WEB-INF/myApp-servlet.xml")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

---

**My web module**

Structure:

```
src/main/
     java/ --> Rest Endpoints etc.
     webapp/ --> web resources, only important files shown
        WEB-INF/
           myApp-servlet.xml
           web.xml
```

pom.xml:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>web-app</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>some-name</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

web.xml:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

  <display-name>My Web App</display-name>

    <!-- Servlet Configuration -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myApp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myApp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

myApp-servlet.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

       <context:component-scan base-package="some.corp.name.space"/>
       <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

**My Problem**

When I run `Application.java` I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/myApp-servlet.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:329)
    ... 24 more
```

From what I can see, this is because the `maven-war-plugin` only includes classes in the jar it creates and does not include the `webapp` directory.

**My Question**

Is there any way for me to achieve this, with or without the maven-war-plugin?
The most important thing for me is to have the `boot-app` as a separate module.

Comment: Why would you need the boot-app as a separate app, that only complicates things. Next to that `WEB-INF` isn't on the classpath so that wouldn't work regardless what you try.

Comment: We want to keep it separate from the existing application, so that no spring boot specific jars get deployed to the server. I want to know how to include `WEB-INF` on the classpath

Comment: Spring boot doesnt read web.xml by default. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html

Comment: Then why use Spring Boot if you don't want to actually use it... You are then basically deploying something different as you developed/tested...

Comment: @M.Deinum I would guess OP wants to use it to speed up testing. The application logic is no different, be it a traditional web deployment or spring boot deployment.

Comment: but I would suspect you can't do this, as you would have to modify the app as well. Spring Boot is more than just a deployment/run mechanism.